# Скорость Seleniumbase

Tags: python, selenium

Интересно узнать как включить на нем многопоток, а так-же виды его ускорения

Comment: Именно SELENIUMBASE! репутации нехватает

Comment: Так-же знаю про -n=... ( который добавляет фоновые работы ), но незнаю как с ними взаимодействовать и давать им определенную работу!!!!

Comment: Если вы хотите дополнить свой вопрос, для этого нужно нажать на кнопку "Править".